# > Find x, which satisfies the equation: $\sqrt{1-\cos (x)}+\sqrt{1+\cos (x)}=\sqrt 3$; SOLVED

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

*** EDITED ***

*Since I don't wan't to many "votes down" on my question; thereof I re-wrote my question in MathJax:*

I'm currently studying for an admission test and have encountered the following problem;

> Find ***x***, which satisfies the equation:
>    $\sqrt{1-\cos (x)}+\sqrt{1+\cos (x)}=\sqrt 3$;
>
> $ -\pi < x < \pi $.
>
> Thereafter, calculate the sum of all squares of the specific ***x***:s that have satisfied the above equation.
>
> C.A : $ \frac{13\pi ^2}9   $

I'm really not sure how to handle this problem. There are no direct-applicable rules that can compress expressions similar to the L.H.S in this problem. I have noticed the conjugates, but when I extend the expression, there seems to be a dead end? Am I missing something crucial?

I'm thankful for every proposed clue to solve this problem!
//

Comment: Hint: square both sides and simplify as much as you can.

Comment: Have you been able to solve it now?

Comment: Thanks for clues and reply. StackTD, yeah I realized it was quite lazy of me of not making the effort of converting the symbols. Ovi: I think I'm on the right path, if you scroll down to my comments on the answers below, you'll find my process - if it would be interesting!

Comment: I changed my downvote to an upvote upon seeing your improvements. Awesome stuff, Carl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Find ***x***, which satisfies the equation:
>    $\sqrt{1-\cos (x)}+\sqrt{1+\cos (x)}=\sqrt 3$;

Note that both sides are non-negative so you can square both sides:
$$1-\cos x+1+\cos x +2\sqrt{(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)} = 3$$
Now $(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x) = 1-\cos^2x = \sin^2 x$, so with $\sqrt{\sin^2x}=\left|\sin x \right|$, you have:
$$2+2 \left|\sin x \right| = 3 \iff \left|\sin x \right| = \tfrac{1}{2} \iff \sin x = \pm\tfrac{1}{2}$$
Can you take it from here? Mind the interval you're solving this equation on.

Comment: If I can refer to my comment to above answer, there you'll se my process of calculations. Perhaps you can tell me where in the process of calculations I'm doing wrong? Thanks though!

Comment: @CARL I guess you solved $\sin x = \tfrac{1}{2}$, but since it's actually $|\sin x| = \tfrac{1}{2}$, you can't forget about $\sin x = \color{red}{-} \tfrac{1}{2}$; that should fix the factor 2 (same solutions, different signs).

Comment: Yeah, I got it now! the solutions in quadrants 3 & 4 are missing, considering the absolute value. The solutions for x in those quadrants are therefore x = - pi / 6 and x = - 5*pi / 6; thus the sum of all squares is: pi^2 / 36 + 25*pi^2 / 36 + ( - pi / 6)^2 + (-5*pi / 6)^2 = 26*pi^2 / 36 + 26*pi^2 / 36 = 52*pi^2 / 36 = 13*pi^2 / 9; TYVM!

Comment: @CARL Indeed! Careful to simply 'cancel' a square root with a square, remember $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$. Note that since sine is an odd function, this will give you the same solutions with opposite signs but those signs disappear after squaring so in fact you simply have to double your answer from before, hence the missing factor 2.

Comment: Yes I will! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

hint: square both sides, don't forget the formula: $1 -\cos^2 \theta = \sin^2 \theta$

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the clue! But when I'm doing so, I'll end up with sin(x)=1/2;       which I solve for x = pi / 6 and x = 5*pi / 6;    Then, the sum of the squares, I get: pi^2 / 36 + 25*pi^2/36 = 26*pi^2 / 36 => 13*pi^2 / 18; It seems that I'm missing a factor of 2 somewhere...

Comment: @CARL You're missing half of the solutions (absolute value!), see my other answer.